# reading text on file and verifying through an array on java

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

So basically i have to verify how many times words are counted within a file on an array.

Edit#2 ( i will run this program through cmd after)

This program takes a number of command line arguments:

1) The file to open

2+) The words to search for and count

If you don’t give it any words to search for, it defaults to these words: "doctor",
"frankenstein", "the", "monster", "igor", "student", "college", "lightning",
"electricity", "blood", and "soul".
You may want to run it with fewer or different words, eg:

```
$ java ReadSearchAndSort frankenstein.txt frankenstein doctor igor monster
```

Edit/Update*: 
If we consider the simple program:

```
public class CopyCat{
public static void main(String[] arguments){
for (int ii = 0; ii < arguments.length; ii++){
System.out.println("Argument "+ ii + " = " +
arguments[ii]);
}
}
}
```

Then if we run it as such:

```
$ java CopyCat a b c
```

we will get the following output

```
Argument 0 = a
Argument 1 = b
Argument 2 = c
```

Using this as your basis:
Get the first argument and store it in a String named `filename`
● Get the rest of the arguments and place them in a String array named
`queryWords` (this should be of the correct size to hold all of the words to count,
and there should be no maximum size — ignoring memory demands of your
system)

Loop through the scanner while things remain in the file ( i.e. `hasNext()` is true)
and get the next word in the file (i.e. call next())
● Put the word in an array — note, you will need to constantly resize the array —
○ So first instantiate an empty array, outside of the for loop

```
String[] words = new String[0]();
```

○ Then, when you read a word, resize the array using `Arrays.copyof`, i.e.

```
words = Arrays.copyOf(words, words.length+1)
```

○ Then place the word in the last spot of the array
■ … but first, we want to make it lower case

```
word = word.toLowerCase();
```

■ and remove all of the non-letters

```
word = word.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "");
```

For each word in our words list, we need to go through the array of words we have read
in, and count each instance. To do this we will make a helper function:
Implementing the function ​`countWordsInUnsorted`

Create a counter variable to record how many times we have seen a word. Create a
loop that iterates over every word in the array. Each time a word matches the query word, increment the counter. We need to use the `equals` method, since we care about whether two strings have the same characters in them, not that they are the exact same
object.

Once you’ve completed the two tasks above, you can run your code. Verify that
`"frankenstein"` appears 26 times

Overall im having trouble understanding the directions and how i should order my code so its understandable. If you can help in anyway i would appreciate it. I know its quite long, but this isnt even whole assignment so its shortened.

EDIT 9/7/18 updates instructions
Timing things in Java
How long did your code take to run?

In this assignment, we will see some search algorithms run faster than others. To seehow much faster, we will record how long the code takes to run.

Here is an example of timing code:

```
// Look at the clock when we start
long t0 = (new Date()).getTime();
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
 // Do something that takes time
}
```

// Look at the clock when we are finished

```
long t1 = (new Date()).getTime();
long elapsed = t1 - t0;
System.out.println("My code took " + elapsed + "milliseconds to
run.")
```

This is already set up for you in main and will output how long your code took to run.
Your job is to implement and call your functions, and make sure that they are working
correctly. If you look in the starter code, you’ll see that we’re running your two different
search and count methods 100 times, so as to get a good average value for how long it
takes. We’re only do the sort once, as sorting the array of 75289 words already takes
awhile.
4. Sorting an array of words with Merge Sort
(35 points)
● Implement mergeSort (Do not​ use Java's built-in Array.sort for this assignment)
● Call your new method in main
● Checking if you are right:​ the words (after SORTED in the output) will be in
alphabetical order.
Implementing ​`mergeSort`
Implement a `mergeSort` method that sorts an array of strings. The signature for this
method should be:

```
public static void mergeSort(String[] arrayToSort, String[]
tempArray, int first, int last)
```

The first argument is the `String[]` to sort, the second argument is an empty temporary
array that should be the same size as the array to sort, the third argument is the starting
index for the portion of the array you want to sort, and the fourth argument is the ending
index for the portion of the array you want to sort.

Note that the version of mergeSort we’ll be implementing sorts arrayToSort in place.
This means that you pass an unsorted array in to mergeSort and after the call that

same array is now sorted.
Note that mergeSort involves comparing to values to see which is larger. With numbers
you can just use < or > to compare them.

if you have two Strings s1 and s2, then:
● `s1.compareTo(s2) == 0` if s1 and s2 contain the same string.

● `s1.compareTo(s2) < 0` if s1 would be alphabetically ordered before s2.

● `s1.compareTo(s2) > 0` if s1 would be alphabetically ordered after s2.

Calling ​`mergeSort​` in ​main

To call `mergeSort` in main, you first need to create a temporary string array that is the same length as `allWords`.

We want to sort the whole array, so the third argument should be the index of the first word in `allWords` and the fourth argument should be the
index of the last word in `allWords`. The four arguments to call mergeSort with are then:

● The array we’re sorting, which is `allWords`.

● Our new temporary array we’ve created that’s the same length as `allWords`.

● The index of the first word in `allWords` (hint: what’s always the index of the very first element of an array?).

● The index of the last word in `allWords` (hint: if you know the length of an array, you can easily compute the index of the last element).

Checking you are right
Did this sort the array of words? The program prints every 500th word. Do they look
sorted?
5. Counting words (with Binary Search) and timing it
(35 points)

● Implement

```
public static int binarySearch(String[] sortedWords,
String query, int startIndex, int endIndex)
```

● Implement

```
public static int getSmallestIndex(String[] words,
String query, int startIndex, int endIndex)
```

● Implement

```
public static int getLargestIndex(String[] words, String
query, int startIndex, int endIndex)
```

● Call `getSmallestIndex` and `getLargestIndex` in main to get the smallest and

largest indices at which the word you’re looking for appears in the sorted array.

Use these two values to compute how many times that word appears.
● Checking if you are right:​ you will get the same values as in the first search section, but much faster.

Implementing ​binarySearch
The arguments to binarySearch are:
● The sorted array of words to search in.
● The word to search for.
● The index in the array at which to start searching.
● The index in the array at which to stop searching.
Binary search returns the array index where it found the word. If the word only appears once in the array, then this index will be where it occurs.

But if the word appears multiple times in the sorted array (so all the instances of the word will be next to eachother in the array), then this index will be to one of the words in the middle of the group.

The binary search algorithm doesn’t guarantee that this will be the first element in the group or the last element in the group. 
So we need to implement some other methods to do this.

Implementing ​`getSmallestIndex`
The method `getSmallestIndex` will be a recursive method that uses the
`binarySearch` method to find the smallest index for which a word is found in the array.
The outline for this method is:
● Use `binarySearch` to find an index to the word. If the index `binarySearch`
returns is -1, then the word wasn’t found and `getSmallestIndex` should just
return -1. This is the base case.
● If `binarySearch` did find the word, then recursively call `getSmallestIndex` on
the portion of the array before where the word was found. This is from index 0 up
to (but not including) the index where the word was found. If this returns -1 then
we know we already had the smallest index, otherwise the recursive call to
`getSmallestIndex` found the smallest index and we should return that. This is
the recursive case.
Implementing ​`getLargestIndex`
The method `getLargestIndex` will be a recursive method that uses the binarySearch
method to find the largest index for which a word is found in the array. The outline for
this method is very similar to the outline above for `getSmallestIndex`, except that the
recursive call should search the portion of the array starting after where binarySearch
has found the word.
Using ​`getSmallestIndex`​ and ​`getLargestIndex`​ in ​main​ to count words
Since the array that you’re working with has been sorted by this point, all the same
words appear next to each other (e.g. all 26 appearances of the word "frankenstein"
are next to each other in the array). So if you’ve found the smallest and largest index for
a word, then you can just subtract the two indices to count the words! But it’s not quite
word appears only once (so the first and last index are the same) and the case where
the word doesn’t appear at all.
Checking if you are right
Check that you’re getting the same answers as the naive approach that iterates through
the whole array. Also, look to see how much faster this approach is to the naive
approach!
Example arguments and output

```
$​ java ReadSearchAndSort frankenstein.txt student college frankenstein blood the
Arguments: use ''student,college,frankenstein,blood,the'' words, time 100 iterations, search for words:
student,college,frankenstein,blood,the
NAIVE SEARCH:
student:2
college:3
frankenstein:26
blood:19
the:4194
96 ms for 500 searches, 0.192000 ms per search
SORTING:
38 ms to sort 75097 words
SORTED (every 498 word): a a aboard affection all although ancient and and and and and angel approached
as asked attended be been believe boat but but by cause clerval comprehensive continued country dante
decay desire died do duvillard end escape exception eyes favourite few flourishing for frankenstein from
girl grief had happiness have he heart her his histories however i i i i i ice impossible in in
inhabitants investigating it its know leaves limbs love man me me might mixture most my my my my nature
no not oatmeal of of of of of old on or over passed philosophy possession profoundly rain regular
resolve room saved seem shape should smiles some spirit straw sun tavernier that that the the the the
the the the the the then thick those time to to to to town uncle upon vessels was was was were when
which while will with with would you you
BINARY SEARCH:
student:2
college:3
frankenstein:26
blood:19
the:4194
6 ms for 500 searches, 0.012000 ms per search
```

Of course the actual timing for running the searches and sort will vary on your computer,
depending on how fast your computer is and how many other processes are running on it.

EDIT 9/7/18

```
 import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadSearchAndSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String filename = args[0];
        int n = args.length - 1;
        String[] queryWords = null;
        String[] allWords = readWords("frankenstein.txt");
        String[] tempAllWords = new String[allWords.length];
        if (n > 0) { //if user provides the querywords
            queryWords = new String[n];
            for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
                queryWords[i - 1] = args[i];
            }
        } else { //if user doesn't provide querywords
            queryWords = new String[]{"doctor", "frankenstein", "the", "monster", "igor", "student", "college", "lightning", "electricity", "blood", "soul"};
        }
        ReadSearchAndSort.readWords("C:/Users/Jordles/IdeaProjects/TimeConversionToSecond.java/out/production/GettingStarted/cs141/frankenstein.txt");


        int timingCount = 100;
        System.out.println("\nArguments: use '" + String.join(",", queryWords) + "' words, time " + timingCount + " iterations, search for words: " + String.join(",", queryWords) + "\n");


        System.out.println("NAIVE SEARCH:");


        // Record the current time
        long t0 = new Date().getTime();

        // Time how long it takes to run timingCount loops
        //   for countWordsInUnsorted
        for (int j = 0; j < timingCount; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < queryWords.length; i++) {
                int count = countWordsInUnsorted(allWords, queryWords[i]);
                if (j == 0) {
                    System.out.println(queryWords[i] + ":" + count);
                }
            }
        }

        long t1 = (new Date()).getTime();

        long timeToSearchNaive = t1 - t0;
        int searchCount = timingCount * queryWords.length;

        // Output how long the searches took, for how many searches
        // (remember: searches = timingcount * the number of words searched)
        int searches = timingCount * 500;
        System.out.printf("%d ms for %d searches, %f ms per search\n", timeToSearchNaive, searchCount, timeToSearchNaive * 1.0f / searchCount);

        // Sort the list of words
        System.out.println("\nSORTING: ");
        mergeSort(allWords, tempAllWords, 0, allWords.length);

        long t2 = (new Date()).getTime();

        // Output how long the sorting took
        long timeToSort = t2 - t1;
        System.out.printf("%d ms to sort %d words\n", timeToSort, allWords.length);

        // Output every 1000th word of your sorted wordlist
        int step = (int) (allWords.length * .00663 + 1);
        System.out.print("\nSORTED (every " + step + " word): ");
        for (int i = 0; i < allWords.length; i++) {
            if (i % step == 0)
                System.out.print(allWords[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");


        System.out.println("BINARY SEARCH:");

        // Run timingCount loops for countWordsInSorted
        // for the first loop, output the count for each word

        for (int j = 0; j < timingCount; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < queryWords.length; i++) {
                int count = countWordsInUnsorted(allWords, queryWords[i]);
                if (j == 0) {
                    System.out.println(queryWords[i] + ":" + count);
                }
            }
        }
        long t3 = (new Date()).getTime();

        long timeToSearchBinary = t3 - t2;
        System.out.printf("%d ms for %d searches, %f ms per search\n", timeToSearchBinary, searchCount, timeToSearchBinary*1.0f/searchCount);

    }
    public static String[] readWords(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException{
        String[] words = new String[0];
        int i = 0;

        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file, "UTF-8");
        input.useDelimiter("\\s+|\\-");

        while(input.hasNext()){
            String word = input.next();
            word = word.toLowerCase();
            word = word.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "");
            words = Arrays.copyOf(words, words.length + 1);
            words[i++] = word;
        }
        return null;
    }


    public static int countWordsInUnsorted(String[] WordsToCount, String countedWord){
        if ((countedWord == null) || (WordsToCount == null)){
            return 0;
        }
        int counter = 0;
        for( String word : WordsToCount){
            if (word.equals(countedWord)){
                counter++;
            }
        }

        return counter;
    }
    public static void mergeSort(String[] arrayToSort, String[] tempArray, int first, int last){
        if (first == last){
            return;
        }
        int mid = (first + last)/2;
        mergeSort(arrayToSort, tempArray, first, mid);
        mergeSort(arrayToSort, tempArray, mid + 1, last);
        merge(arrayToSort, tempArray, first, mid, mid + 1, last);


    }
    public static void merge(String[] arrayToSort, String[] tempArray, int first, int mid, int mid1, int last){
        int j = first;
        int k = mid1;
        int l = first;
        do{
            if (tempArray[j].compareTo(tempArray[k]) < 0){
                arrayToSort[l] = tempArray[j];
                j++;
            }
            else{
                arrayToSort[l] = tempArray[k];
                k++;
            }
        }
        while (j <= mid && k <= last){

        }
    }
    public static int binarySearch(String[] sortedWords, String query, int startIndex, int endIndex){
        if (startIndex > endIndex){

        }
        int mid = (startIndex + endIndex)/2;
        if(query.compareTo(sortedWords[mid]) == 0){
            return;
        }
        if (query.compareTo(sortedWords[mid]) < 0){
            binarySearch(sortedWords, query, startIndex, mid -1 );
        }
        if (query.compareTo(sortedWords[mid]) > 0){
            binarySearch(sortedWords, query, mid + 1, endIndex);
        }
        return -1;
    }
    public static int getSmallestIndex(String[] words, String query, int startIndex, int endIndex){
        return -1;
    }
    public static int getLargestIndex(String[] words, String query, int startIndex, int endIndex){
        return -1;
    }
    public static int countWordsInSorted(String[] wordsTocount, String countedWord){
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: toLowerCase() is a method of String not of String[].

Comment: Throw this program away and start new from scratch. And work step by step. That means: first make a programm that "Get the first argument and store it in a String named filename". Than test that the program is doing it correctly. Than extend your programm with the next step and test it again. And so on.

Comment: ok so ive updated at the top to show more context, im not sure how the following sample code ties into my arguments? (this is being ran in cmd after im done) do i use scanner and input the arguments myself? Are the words in my file the arguments? If its obvious, im sorry i just dont understand whats being asked.

Comment: @Ralf Renz How do i pass the string to an array then to make toLowerCase() work?

Comment: The other way around: first you make toLowerCase() to the string and after that you add the modified string to the array.

Comment: If you are constantly increasing the array size, then you should use a `List`, such as `ArrayList`.

Comment: @LAD my parameters for this assignment doesnt include using ArrayList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `readWords` method you should call `.toLowerCase()` and `.replaceAll()` only after reading the word form the file.

Edit: The `return null;` must not be the only return of the method, otherwise you're just throwing away everything the method did. You could use it to handle error, but I strongly suggest to return an empty array.
If you return an empty array (or collection), you avoid surprising consumers (whoever call your method) of this method with an unintentional NullPointerException, so so they don't have to guard against it.

Take also a look at the tutorial for [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) I've used.

```
public static String[] readWords(final String filename) {
    // Check on input
    if (filename == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String[] words = new String[0];
    int i = 0; // index of the first empty position in the array
    final File inputFile = new File(filename);
    try (Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile)) {
        in.useDelimiter("\\s+|\\-");
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            String word = in.next().toLowerCase();
            word = word.replaceAll("[^a-z ]", ""); // No need of A-Z since we called .toLowerCase()
            words = Arrays.copyOf(words, words.length + 1);
            words[i++] = word; // Put the current word at the bottom of the array, then increment the index
        }
    } catch (final FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("The file " + filename + " does not exist");
        return null;
    }

    return words;
}
```

The method is very simple, I suggest using the [enhanced for loop](https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/enhanced-for-loop).
Please also consider [Java naming conventions](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions): variable name should start with lowercase letter.
Edit: same here about the `return 0;`. It must not be the only return of the method.

```
public static int countWordsInUnsorted(final String searchedWord, final String[] words) {
    // Check on input
    if ((searchedWord == null) || (words == null)) {
        return 0;
    }

    int count = 0;
    for (final String word : words) {
        if (word.equals(searchedWord)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

**Edit4**:

> This program takes one command line argument: the words to search for and count.
>   java SearchAndSort "frankenstein,doctor,igor,monster"

Since the assignement uses a comma as separator, you can use [String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) to get the array of strings.

Due to the need of calculating the elapsed time, you cannot search and print the words: the print operation is very time expensive, so it would distort the result. That's why I used an array of int to store the count of every word.
`int[] wordsCounter = new int[queryWords.length];`

In order to calculate the time per search, you need a `double`, but if you do an arithmetic operation between `long`, you'll always get a `long`. That's why you need to cast at least one operand to `double`.
`double timePerSearch = ((double) elapsedTime) / totalSearches;`

Refactored main method:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    // Default words to search for
    String queryWordsString = "doctor,frankenstein,the,monster,igor,student,college,lightning,electricity,blood,soul";

    if (args.length > 0) { // If the user provided  query words
        queryWordsString = args[0];
    }

    final String[] queryWords = queryWordsString.split(","); // split the string into an array

    System.out.println("SEARCH AND SORT");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Searching and counting the words " + queryWordsString); // print the words to search for
    System.out.println();

    // Just the name of the file if it's in the same directory of program
    // The absolute path if they are in different directory
    final String filename = "frankenstein.txt";

    // Read words from file
    final String[] words = SearchAndSort.readWords(filename);
    if (words == null) {
        return;
    }

    final int[] wordsCounter = new int[queryWords.length];

    // Store the starting time
    final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // Search the words and store their count
    for (int i = 0; i < queryWords.length; i++) {
        final int count = SearchAndSort.countWordsInUnsorted(queryWords[i], words);
        wordsCounter[i] = count;
    }

    final long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

    System.out.println("NAIVE SEARCH:");
    // Print how many time each word appears
    for (int i = 0; i < queryWords.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(queryWords[i] + ": " + wordsCounter[i]);
    }

    final int totalSearches = queryWords.length * words.length;
    final double timePerSearch = ((double) elapsedTime) / totalSearches;
    // Print the elapsed time in ms
    System.out.println(elapsedTime + " ms for " + totalSearches + " searches, " + timePerSearch + " ms per search");
}
```

**Edit4**:

```
long t0 = ( new Date()).getTime();  
for (var i = 0 ; i < 100000 ; i++) {  
    // Do something that takes time  
}
```

In this example the `100000` isn't a new variable, it's the standard upper limit of the for loop you're going to use. It's `queryWords.length` for *NAIVE SEARCH:* block and `words.length` for *SORTING:* block.

Edit:

```
// Record the current time  
long t0 = (new Date()).getTime();
```

Don't do this. If you want to measure elapsed time, you should use `long t0 = System.nanoTime()`. From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime())

> Returns the current value of the running Java Virtual Machine's high-resolution time source, in nanoseconds.
>
> This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time. The value returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary origin time (perhaps in the future, so values may be negative). The same origin is used by all invocations of this method in an instance of a Java virtual machine; other virtual machine instances are likely to use a different origin.
>
> This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond resolution (that is, how frequently the value changes) - no guarantees are made except that the resolution is at least as good as that of currentTimeMillis().
>   [...]
>   The values returned by this method become meaningful only when the difference between two such values, obtained within the same instance of a Java virtual machine, is computed.
>
> For example, to measure how long some code takes to execute:

Probably you would read [System.currentTimeMillis() documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) too.

Comment: As I understand, "frankenstein" should be an example for a queryWord. That means, the program should be started with the parameters for the filename and the queryword "frankenstein".

Comment: @RalfRenz Indeed the program get the filename and queryWords from parameters (5th line of the `main` method). It also prints the occurrence of every queryWords (22th line). I've left the "frankenstein" just as example for the `countWordsInUnsorted` method. Anyway that method became useless due to the Map.

Comment: Using maps and lambdas and enhanced for-loops is nice for someone who knows how to program. But Jordles just a beginner. Simple arrays and loops would be better.

Comment: Ruben DG  & @Ralf Renz I really appreciate the help :D, ill look through all this and try to incorporate that into my code. Unfortunately i cant use anything advanced like map, as my professor wouldn't allow it. I do have to ask, what parameters do filename and queryWord fit into? The CountWordsInUnsorted method? In general, this entire assignment is confusing because i dont know which and what each variable does and where i should refer to them. I know im not just checking for "frankenstein", as this assignment is to check lots of words in a file.

Comment: @Jordles I edited the answer. You must provide the filename and the words you want to search as you did in your example `java CopyCat a b c`. 'a' will be the filename (the first parameter), 'b' and 'c' will be put into queryWords array and will be serached into the file *a*. The `countWordsInUnsorted` takes the word you want to search and the array into which you will search that word.

Comment: @Ruben DG i actually have a sheet here that tells me what i should be putting in my program. so return null and 0 are supposed to be in there. Do you know what "return 0" does for the method? I updated above to show, what the parameters im entering i think?

Comment: @Ruben DG i just read an update on the assignment, however i cannot use Array Copying

Comment: @Jordles I've updated the answer. You can use "return 0" and "return null" in case of errors. Anyway it's a good practice to return an empty collection/array instead of returning `null`. By the way, please consider [vote or accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you found it useful.

Comment: @Ruben DG of course! thanks so much for investing all your time to help me! I tried voting but my reputation is too low cause im a new user. For the variable filename, why did you make it equal to args[0], i thought it was referring to the filename im using. Would filename = "frankenstein.txt" not be correct?

Comment: @Jordles You stated that the filename is the first paramenter `This program takes a number of command line arguments: 1) The file to open`. `args[0]` is the first parameter, so if you run `java ReadSearchAndSort frankenstein.txt frankenstein doctor igor monster`, `args[0]` will contain "frankenstein.txt". Updated the answer

Comment: Ive seen you made some edits, most of the things i put up are already suppose to be on the code. For more context, i just put the entire assignment. If you dont want to invest anymore time though, its fine because i know its very long which i why initially i just cropped out and focused on 1/3 of the code.

Comment: @Ruben DG here is a more readable file for the instructions https://canvas.ucsc.edu/courses/12730/files/548050/download?verifier=4tLurjYjWzlcliCXhzSSX47xQM1EHueJtv3pIVhb&wrap=1

Comment: @Jordles Updated the `main` method, look for **Edit4**. [Sorting.at](http://sorting.at/) is a nice site to visualize what each sorting algorithm does.

Comment: @Jordles I've read the assignment and you are not forced to use the example code... it's only an example. The only *must* are the methods signature and the file name `SearchAndSort.java`. About the `return 0` or `return null`, I think they are there only because your teacher provided the skeleton of those method and without those return the code wouldn't compile (and no one likes seeing error in their IDE). Of course you **must** change them once you implemented the methods. Good luck for your exams.